# How can I transfer photos over SnapBridge that are taken after the 9999th photo?

Tags: nikon, snapbridge

I have a Nikon Coolpix B500 camera. I have reached 9999 photos in my camera gallery, however I can take more photos without a problem. When I look the photos taken after the 9999th photo, they're in the gallery of the camera.

I use [SnapBridge](https://snapbridge.nikon.com/) to transfer the photos to my phone however it will only load the first 9999 photos. All the photos I took after that won't load. I know the photos are there as I can view them in the camera.

How can I use SnapBridge to transfer the photos that I took after my 9999<sup>th</sup> photo to my phone?

Answer (score 1):

In the snapbridge app, when you click on the download photos menu, There is a display setting that can be selected to choose which folder to display ( or it can be set to display ALL folders.) It is in the same setting menu, where you choose whether to display the RAW files or the JPEG files.

If after the 9999th image , the camera created a new folder and the display setting does not include that folder, then it wont be displayed.

To be safe, i have kept the setting at "display all folders" .I would suggest you do the same if you have not done that

Answer (score -1):

Most DSLRs, when they roll over, will create a new sub-directory under `DCIM`, the naming of which often can be controlled by some of the configuration options in the camera menu, and then start over with images numbering from `0000` in that new directory.

I don't use SnapBridge, so I'm not sure how to tell it to switch to the new directory, but I would guess there would have to be an option to do that somehow...

Comment: But how does one enter that new folder via SnapBridge? I understood that as the essence of the question.